# Can I pass printf output into a variable in PHP?

Tags: variables, output, printf

Not a programmer. I don't understand how the following code works. But I know it prints the greeting "Hello *logged in user*

Here is the code:

```
    $current_user = get_current_user();
    printf( __( 'Hello %s', 'textdomain' ), esc_html( $current_user->user_login ) );
```

I want the user able to click on his name and enter his profile page at "https://example.com/profilepage/"

So basically, I want to do this:

```
    $current_user = get_current_user();
    $usertarget = printf( __( 'Hello %s', 'textdomain' ), esc_html( $current_user->user_login ) );
    echo '<a href="https://example.com/profilepage/">' . $usertarget . '</a>';
```

How can I do this?

Comment: why not use `sprintf( __( 'Hello <a href="https://example.com/profilepage/">%s</a>'`